# strange contact between bodies

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a strange problem.
the shot of my players, when it collides with a body, destroys it without problems, but, when it hits the two bodies at once, it crashes.

shooting player

```
b2Body *shooting = [_lhelper newBodyWithUniqueName:@"shoot" world:_world];
CCSprite *shootingSprite = (CCSprite *)shootingBody->GetUserData();
shootingBody.position = pos;
shootingBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(pos.x/PTM_RATIO, 
                               pos.y/PTM_RATIO), 
                        CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));
```

contact

```
if([spriteA tag] == ENEMY && [spriteB tag] == SHOT)
{


    int animIdx = [(NSNumber*)[spriteA userData] intValue];
    if(animIdx < 2)
    {
        [spriteA setTextureRect:MY_RECTS[animIdx]];
        [spriteA setUserData:[NSNumber numberWithInt:animIdx+1]];
    }
    else
    {
        [objectThatWillBeDeleted addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyA]];

    }

    [objectThatWillBeDeleted addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyB]];

}
else if([spriteB tag] == ENEMY && [spriteA tag] == SHOT)
{


    int animIdx = [(NSNumber*)[spriteB userData] intValue];

    if(animIdx < 2)
    {        
        [spriteB setTextureRect:MY_RECTS[animIdx]];    
        [spriteA setUserData:[NSNumber numberWithInt:animIdx+1]];
    }
    else
    {
        [objectThatWillBeDeleted addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyB]];
    }

    [objectThatWillBeDeleted addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:bodyA]];

}
```

update

```
    std::vector<Contact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
    pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) 
{
    Contact contact = *pos;

    //[self checkBodies2:&contact];         

}


for(NSValue* val in objectThatWillBeDeleted)
{
    b2Body* body = (b2Body*)[val pointerValue];
    [_lhelper removeBody:body];
}

    [objectThatWillBeDeleted removeAllObjects];
}
```

}

I do not understand where the error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand where the error either because you didn't say where it crashes :)
But I would guess you are trying to destroy the same body twice.

When the shot hits two enemies in the same time step, the shot body gets added to the objectThatWillBeDeleted list twice. You just need to make that list unique before you destroy the contents of it.

Comment: A collision contact is reported twice for the same body if it touches two bodies at the same time. This is normal behavior. You should use an NSMutableSet to ensure only one object of a type can exist in objectThatWillBeDeleted. You will probably have to query the NSMutableSet for existence of that body before adding it. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableset_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html